# How to Customize QuickLook(QLPreviewControlller) navigation bar?

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to remove all the right-side `BarButtonItem` in `QuickLook (QLPreviewController)` in iOS 15 and Xcode 13.2 and later.

My requirement is to only show search button in right-side of navigation bar. I tried many types of solutions but I'm not able to meet this requirement. I also read `QuickLook` Document provided by Apple but I'm not having success. For more understanding show this Apple document: [Apple QuickLook Document Link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook).

[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the ability to edit a document while using `QLPreviewController`, you need to implement the `previewController(_:editingModeFor:)` delegate method.

Make sure you set the `delegate` property of your `QLPreviewController` (along with the `dataSource`).

Then implement:

```
func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, editingModeFor previewItem: QLPreviewItem) -> QLPreviewItemEditingMode {
    return .disabled
}
```

This will disable editing and remove the edit icon next to the search icon.

Comment: can you provide me other solution of this, I want to remove down Arrow behind document title and also remove more button option copy action on click doc thumb option, this is show in **IOS 16.2** @HangarRash